# Message no component Snackbar - Angular 4 Material

Tags: typescript, angular-material

Estou usando a biblioteca do angular material e resolvi utilizar o *Component* de [Snackbar](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview).

Um dos parâmetros do *Snackbar* é o parâmetro `message`. Minha intenção é passar dentro do `message` ao invés de uma string o seguinte código *HTML*:

```
<p>Obrigado por ser inscrever</p><br><a href=“” class=“link”>Clique aqui</a> para logar.
```

Como poderia injetar esse *HTML* no parâmetro `message`, sendo que ele aceita apenas uma string (sem class e tags HTML)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em vez de usar o método `open` você deve utilizar o método `openFromComponent` que permite você personalizar o conteúdo do *Snackbar*.

Crie um componente e um template, segue um pequeno exemplo:

> Arquivo *app.component.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar, MatSnackBarRef } from '@angular/material';
@Component({
    selector: 'material-app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent { 
    constructor(public snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}

    /** Método para abrir o Snackbar. */
    openSnackBarMensagem(){
        this.snackBar.openFromComponent(SnackbarMensagemComponent);
    }
}

/** Componente SnackbarMensagem. */
@Component({
    selector: 'snackbar-mensagem',
    templateUrl: 'snackbar.mensagem.html'
})
export class SnackbarMensagemComponent {
    constructor(public snackBarRef: MatSnackBarRef<SnackbarMensagemComponent>) { }
    // Método para fechar
    closeSnackBarMensagem(){
        this.snackBarRef.dismiss();
    }
}
```

> Arquivo *snackbar.mensagem.html*

```
<p>Obrigado por ser inscrever</p><a href="" class="link">Clique aqui</a> para logar.
<button mat-button (click)="closeSnackBarMensagem()">Fechar</button>
```

No arquivo *app.module.ts* você deve importar o componente *SnackbarMensagemComponent*

```
import {AppComponent, SnackbarMensagemComponent} from './app.component';
```

Continuando no arquivo *app.module.ts*, você deve declarar o mesmo como no exemplo abaixo:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
    ],
    entryComponents: [ SnackbarMensagemComponent ],
    declarations: [AppComponent, SnackbarMensagemComponent],
    ...
})
```

> Arquivo *app.component.html*

```
<p>
    <button mat-button (click)="openSnackBarMensagem()">Exibir mensagem</button>
</p>
```

> Você pode ver funcionando no [stackblitz.io](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xomy7e)

#### Referência

- [Snackbar](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api#MatSnackBar)

Comment: muito obrigado pela resposta. O problema agora é com o fechar, eu não estou conseguindo reproduzir o label de fechar na snackbar. Consegue me orientar? O meu código está assim:

Comment: this.snackBar.openFromComponent(SnackbarMessageComponent, { direction: 'ltr', extraClasses: ['show'], duration: 50000 } );     --- Como posso passar o label fechar para ser exibido na snackbar?

Comment: @HitchLeonardo editei a resposta veja como ficou.